# Reassigning class names when item from array is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, rename

I have a table of data the user can input things into:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="wiring_details_6-73" id="wiring_rows_0">
        <td colspan="2"> Wire Type:
            <select class="wire_selector_0" id="wiring_select_0" name="select_wire_6" onchange="Estimate.select_wire( 6, this.value, 0 );">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select wire..</option>
                <option value="1">14/2</option>
                <option value="2">14/4</option>
                <option value="3">16/4</option>
                <option value="4">16/2</option>
                <option value="5">RG6</option>
                <option value="6">CAT5</option>
                <option value="7">RG59</option>
                <option value="8">LVT</option>
                <option value="9">CAT6</option>
                <option value="10">HDMI</option>
                <option value="11">Shielded CAT6</option>
            </select> </td>
        <td colspan="2">Length:
            <input type="text" class="id_wire_length_6" name="wire_length_6" value="0"></td>
        <td colspan="2">Retail Price:
            <input type="text" class="id_wire_retail_6" name="wire_retail_6" value="0"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="wire_total">
            <input type="hidden" id="wire_id_6" name="wire_id_6" value="0"><a href="#" class="delete-button" id="wiring_button_0">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The user can click the "Add wire" link and it will generate another one of the above forms but with the class names of `wire_selector_1`, `wiring_rows_1` and `wiring_button_1` instead of `wire_selector_0`, `wiring_rows_0` and `wiring_button_0`.

Now say the user deletes row `0`, this invokes this code:

```
deleteWire: function(part_id, row) {
        var node = Wireholder.wires[row];
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        Wireholder.wires.splice(row, 1);
        for(var i=0;i<Wireholder.wires.length;i++)
        {
            var selectItem = Wireholder.wires[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            var buttonItem = Wireholder.wires[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            Wireholder.wires[i].id = "wiring_rows_" + i;
            selectItem.id = "wiring_select_" + i;
            buttonItem.id = "wiring_button_" + i;
            selectItem.onchange = function()
            {
                Estimate.select_wire(part_id, this.value, this.id.match(/\d+/));
            }
        }
        Estimate.total();
        return false;
    }
```

This removes the item from the array and splices it.

What I need to happen is for all rows **after** the deleted row have their class names changed from for example:

```
example_class_1 to example_class_0
```

Or

```
example_class_3 to example_class_2
```

To allow for proper item targeting.

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is you want the `className` property to be edited just like the `id` one is in the loop? You would just need to loop through the `wires` array and update `className`s based on the index of the wire in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple looping and property manipulation. Just as your id is changed after an item is deleted, you can adjust the class with `className`.

```
Wireholder.wires[i].className = "convention" + i;
selectItem.className = "convention" + i;
buttonItem.className = "convention" + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do the trick ;)

```
$('tr[class*="example_class_"]').each(function(i, node){
    $(node).attr('class', 'example_class_'+i);
});
```